# Find matching keywords from comma separated

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to find keywords from comma separating string with `FIND_IN_SET` and here is mysql query in `Laravel` framwork.

```
$Keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$Result = DB::table('faqtopic')
    ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?,Keywords)', 'LIKE', ''[$Keyword])
    ->get();
```

### faqtopic table:

```
╔════╦══════════════╗
║ id ║   keywords   ║
╠════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║ php, android ║
║  2 ║ microsoft,net║
║  3 ║ android, ios ║
╚════╩══════════════╝
```

I am getting two results, If I pass `android` keyword but not getting any result I pass only `andro`. I want to get android result If user pass `andro` keyword for search query.

Any Idea how to get this results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$data = modelName::where('filedName', 'like', '%keyword%')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use %

```
$Keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$Result = DB::table('faqtopic')
    ->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?,Keywords)', 'LIKE', '%'.$Keyword.'%')
    ->get();
```